# How to return the value from inside a callback?

Tags: jquery, string, function, callback

This is the function that is supposed to return name :

```
function getLookupNameById(lookup_id, callback){
    var name = "";
    if(lookup_id != 0) {
        updateData({
            lookup_id: lookup_id,
            callback: function(status, data){
                if( status && data.values){
                    values =  data.values;
                    name = somevalue;
                    return name; //returns undefined
                }
                else{
                    console.log('Empty');
                }
                if(callback)
                    callback();
            }
        });
    }
    return name; //returns empty string
}
```

This is how i am calling the function from another script :

```
var name = instanceofscript.getLookupNameById(parameter);
```

How should i return the value??

Comment: Here comes [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and a lot of same questions in SO.

Comment: You're not passing the `callback` parameter.

Comment: it will depend upon `updateData`... whether it is async or synchronized

Comment: Is `updateData()` an asynchronous function? Then `name` won't be set until it executes later, so of course `return name` returns an empty string.

Comment: yes updateData is Async Oh now i see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use asynchrnonous functions, you can't `return` anything from them, since they don't run until after the caller returns. Everything that depends on the returned data has to be done in the callback function.

The `callback` function should receive `name` as a parameter:

```
if (callback) {
    callback(name);
}
```

And then you need to call it like this:

```
instanceofscript.getLookupNameById(parameter, function(name) {
    console.log(name);
});
```

This is essentially the same as using AJAX, so see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)